# How to show tooltip on disabled button and hide tooltip on enabled button using dojo

Tags: dojo, tooltip

need to show tooltip on disabled button and hide tooltip on enabled button using dojo.

I am having a check box  and a button.
On checking the checkbox i need to enable the button, on unchecking I want to disable the button and want a tootip to tell why the button is disabled.

In general scenario for disabled button the tooltip wont come.

I got a code to display the tooltip on a disabed button from the below link
[displaying dojo tooltip on a disabled validation text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377367/displaying-dojo-tooltip-on-a-disabled-validation-text-box)

but i want the tooltip to be hidden on enabling the button . Please provide a solution

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the example in the link [displaying dojo tooltip on a disabled validation text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377367/displaying-dojo-tooltip-on-a-disabled-validation-text-box) to suit your need.

```
html
<span id="abcd">
 <input type="button" disabled="true" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" id="button1" label="MyButton" />
 </span>
<div dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="button1" jsId="tt1" label = "Why the button is disabled?" ></div>
```

Js part

```
<script>
    dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
    dojo.require("dijit.Tooltip");
    dojo.require("dijit.TooltipDialog");
    dojo.require("dojox.fx");

    var dialog;

    dojo.addOnLoad(function() {

        dojo.connect(dijit.byId('button1').domNode,'mouseenter', function(){
            console.log("HI");
            // Modified code ***START***
            var button = dijit.byId('button1');
            var disabled = button.get("disabled");
            if (disabled){ // disabled == true
                tt1.open(this);
            };
            // Modified code ***END***

        })

        dojo.connect(dojo.byId('abcd'),'mouseleave', function(e){
            tt1.close();
            console.log("HI2")
        })


        tt1.addTarget(dojo.query('input', dijit.byId('someId11').domNode));
    });
</script>
```